# How to wrap an init/cleanup function in Boost python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I recently discovered the existence of boost-python and was astonished by it's apparent simplicity. I wanted to give it a try and started to wrap an existing C++ library.

While wrapping the basic library API calls is quite simple (nothing special, just regular function calls and very common parameters), I don't know how to properly wrap the initialization/cleanup functions:

As it stands, my C++ library requires the caller to first call `mylib::initialize()` when the program starts, and to call `mylib::cleanup()` before it ends (actually there is also an initializer object that takes care of that, but it is probably irrelevant).

How should I wrap this using boost python ?

Forcing a Python user to call `mymodule.initialize()` and `mymodule.cleanup()` seems not very *pythonic*. Is there any way to that in an automatic fashion ? Ideally, the call to `initialize()` would be done transparently when the module is imported and the call to `cleanup()` also done when the python script ends.

Is there any way to do that ? If not, what is the most elegant solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to do a guard object and assign it to a hidden attribute of your module.

```
struct MyLibGuard
{
    MyLibGuard() { myLib::initialize();}
    ~MyLibGuard() { myLib::cleanup();}
};

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(arch_lib)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MyLibGuard> libGuard = new MyLibGuard();

    class_<MyLibGuard, boost::shared_ptr<MyLibGuard>, boost::noncopyable>("MyLibGuard", no_init);
    scope().attr("__libguard") = libGuard;

}
```

Comment: I see this as the best way to do it. Oftentimes with boost::python if you need specialize functionality you just create a simple struct as was done above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try and keep you posted :)

Comment: I had to replace `class__` with `class_` to be able to compile. And had to switch() the last 2 lines so that python doesn't complain. Thank you very much. Do you mind if I edit to your answer to reflect the changes ?